# getting error on setAdapter in AsyncTAsk?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I added the Row_Cursor_Adapter globally and made changes after adding onPostExecute() method in the Service_ivr AsyncTask.This is the updated code.

```
 class Service_ivr extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
     {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... param) 
        {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE ,METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("user_id",param[0]);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.bodyOut=request;
            envelope.dotNet =true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            try
            {
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapObject obj2 = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                int count = obj2.getPropertyCount();
                index = count/7;
                final lead_content_IVR [] total_ivr_data = new lead_content_IVR[index];
                for(int i=0; i<index ;i++)
                {
                    String call_duration;
                    String lead_id = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+0);
                    String lead_call_from = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+1);
                    String lead_call_to = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+2);
                    String lead_date=obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+3);
                    String lead_audio=obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+4);
                    String assign_id = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+5);
                    String time = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+6);
                    if(lead_call_from.equals("Welcome Sound") || lead_call_from.equals("Call Missed") || lead_call_from.equals("User Disconnected")  || lead_call_from.equals("Customer Missed"))
                    {
                        call_duration= "5 sec";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        call_duration = time.toString().concat(" sec");
                    }

                    total_ivr_data[i] = new lead_content_IVR(lead_id,lead_call_from,lead_call_to,lead_date,lead_audio,assign_id,call_duration);
                }

                adapter = new RowCursorAdapter_IVR(Activity_IVR_Lead.this, R.layout.listview_layout_ivr,total_ivr_data);





            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
             super.onPostExecute(s);
             listView.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
     }
```

As u suggest i update the code but error is same all the time.

Comment: Move `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` line inside onPostExecute method

Comment: thanks for quick response...

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                 super.onPostExecute(s);
                 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             }

Comment: Also declare `RowCursorAdapter_IVR adapter ` globally and use `adapter = new RowCursorAdapter_IVR(Activity_IVR_Lead.this, R.layout.listview_layout_ivr,total_ivr_data);`

Comment: again error is same can not resolve symbol in                               @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                 super.onPostExecute(s);
                 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             }

Comment: show your updated code

Comment: i will re post my code

Comment: what is the error you are getting .

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like so

```
class service_ivr extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    @Override
    protected lead_content_IVR[]  doInBackground(String... param) 
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE ,METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("user_id",param[0]);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.bodyOut=request;
        envelope.dotNet =true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        lead_content_IVR [] total_ivr_data = null;
        try
        {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject obj2 = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            int count = obj2.getPropertyCount();
            index = count/7;
            total_ivr_data = new lead_content_IVR[index];
            for(int i=0; i<index ;i++)
            {
                String call_duration;
                String lead_id = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+0);
                String lead_call_from = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+1);
                String lead_call_to = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+2);
                String lead_date=obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+3);
                String lead_audio=obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+4);
                String assign_id = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+5);
                String time = obj2.getPropertyAsString(i*7+6);
                if(lead_call_from.equals("Welcome Sound") || lead_call_from.equals("Call Missed") || lead_call_from.equals("User Disconnected")  || lead_call_from.equals("Customer Missed"))
                {
                    call_duration= "5 sec";
                }
                else
                {
                    call_duration = time.toString().concat(" sec");
                }

                total_ivr_data[i] = new lead_content_IVR(lead_id,lead_call_from,lead_call_to,lead_date,lead_audio,assign_id,call_duration);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return total_ivr_data;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(lead_content_IVR [] total_ivr_data ) {
        RowCursorAdapter_IVR adapter = new RowCursorAdapter_IVR(Activity_IVR_Lead.this, R.layout.listview_layout_ivr,total_ivr_data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```